# How to stop displaying dropdown-box in Angular Material mautocomplete when I click on the input field?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

```js
export class AutocompleteSimpleExample {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
}
```

```html
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Problem is when I click on input-box than dropdown-box is open.
But I got, when I click on input-box than not open dropdown box, dropdown box is open when enter in some text only. So how I fix this?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, would you mind elaborating this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56581215/angular-material-autocomplete-onfocus-keep-suggestion-panel-closed/56581724#56581724

Comment: the problem is when i click on input field than open option box, but solution is when focus or click on input field than not open option box if input box null